# Finite square well bound states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

Let's suppose I have a [finite potential well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well): $$
V(x)=
\begin{cases}
\infty,\quad x<0\\
0,\quad 0<x<a\\
V_o,\quad x>a.
\end{cases}
$$

I solved the time-independent Schrodinger equation for each region and after applying the continuity conditions of $\Psi$ and its derivative I ended up with:

$$ \tan(k_1a)=-\frac{k_1}{k_2},$$ where $k_1=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}$ and $k_2=\sqrt{\frac{2m(V_o-E)}{\hbar^2}}$.

I'm aware of the fact that solutions can only be calculated graphically, but what's the relation between the value of $V_o$ and the bound states? What if I want to find the acceptable values of $V_o$ for the bound states to be $1,2,3,\dots$ or none?

Comment: Do you mean what is the relation between $V_0$ and the *number* of bound states? It just depends on​ how many zeros that transcendental equation has. I don't believe there is a way to figure it out *a priori*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to reorganize your equation so that
$$
\tan\left(\sqrt{\frac{2m V_0 a^2}{\hbar^2}\frac{E}{V_0}}\right)
=-\sqrt{\frac{E/V_0}{1-E/V_0}}
$$
and define the dimensionless variables 
$$
z=\frac{E}{V_0}\, ,\qquad \xi= \frac{2m V_0 a^2}{\hbar^2}
$$
The possible eigenvalues are then given by finding the roots of
$$
\tan\sqrt{\xi z}=-\sqrt{\frac{z}{1-z}}\, .
$$
In principle,  you will know or fix the various variables in 
$\xi$ so that by changing $V_0$ you change $\xi$ and thus the values of $z$ for which there is intersection.

Obviously, the number of bound states will be determined by the number of times $\tan\sqrt{\xi z}$ intersects the other curves, which is always negative.  Since $0\le z\le 1$, you will not get any bound state for $\xi<(\pi/2)^2$ since, in this region, $\tan\sqrt{\xi z}$ will never be negative.  However, with (for instance) $\xi=1.1(\pi/2)^2$ you find a single intersection at $z=0.969$, meaning $E=0.969 V_0$, really close to the lip of your potential.  The lowest value of $\xi$ for you will have 2 intersections is $\xi=(3\pi/2)^2$. 
 For $\xi=1.1\times (3\pi/2)^2$ there are 2 solutions: $z_1=0.274$ and $z_2=0.973$ etc.